# Where should I put DataGrip database driver on linux?

Tags: database, datagrip

Need to install Postgre database driver on my PC for DataGrip, my PC has no internet.

I has this jar file on my PC desktop, but in what place should I put this jar file?

So on Windows, it was `~\.DataGrip2019.2\config\jdbc-drivers`, but what directory on Linux?

Comment: On my Linux Mint system it was ~/.config/JetBrains/DataGrip2023.3/jdbc-drivers/
DataGrip tried to load the newest mysql driver - so the path
MySQL ConnectorJ/8.0.25/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.25/ was already there.
I downloaded mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar and mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.pom there and set up an new Source (clicked on download again i think) to make DataGrip recognize the driver. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Data source & Drivers dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/other-databases.html#using-user-driver-files) switch to Drivers tab, select target driver, on driver files pane remove current entry, then click (+) -> Custom JARs -> select your file and that's it.